# How to function call using 'this' inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, function, foreach, this

In the following object, I have a problem using the 'this' reference:

```
function SampleObject(){
    this.addObject = function(object){...}
    ...
    // more code here
    ...
    this.addNewObjects= function(arr){
        arr.forEach( function (obj) {
            this.addObject(new Obj(obj.prop1, obj.prop2));
        });
    }
}
```

I'm assuming the context is changing and that 'this' refers the iterated 'obj', and not 'SampleObject'. I've solved the problem using a normal for loop however, i'm curuois to why this is not working, and would like to know if there is another way to do this.

Comment: Where/how do you call `SampleObject()`?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on `this`:    [here](http://toddmotto.com/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/) or [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

Comment: @javinor thanks, these articles were very helpfull. Function creates scope, and so 'this' is owned by the Window object, which is the default owner of 'this'.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of Owner of "this" at all.

Answer (score 138):

You can store this in variable:

```
var self = this;
this.addNewObjects = function(arr){
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        self.addObject(new Obj(obj.prop1, obj.prop2));
    });
}
```

or use bind:

```
this.addNewObjects = function(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        this.addObject(new Obj(obj.prop1, obj.prop2));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

And side note, without those `this` will be window object not obj. `This` is always object that was created using new keyword or window object if it's normal function. In strict mode `this` will be undefined in this case.

**UPDATE**: and with ES6 you can use arrow function:

```
this.addNewObjects = function(arr) {
    arr.forEach((obj) => {
        this.addObject(new Obj(obj.prop1, obj.prop2));
    });
}
```

arrow functions don't have their own `this` and they get it from outer scope.

**UPDATE2**: from @viery365 comment you can use this as second argument to forEach and it will make context for the function:

```
this.addNewObjects = function(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        this.addObject(new Obj(obj.prop1, obj.prop2));
    }, this);
}
```

You can read this on [MDN forEach page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: In the case of `forEach()`(related to the question) one can also use the 'built-in' second parameter - `thisArg` after the callback. Example: `arr.forEach(callback, this);` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @viery365 Oh didn't know that, you should add your own answer with our solution. That may be better for just `forEach()`.

Comment: There is no option to answer for this particular question maybe because was marked as a duplicate. But anyway your answer is almost perfect and I also learnt from it. My comment was just a complement.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array1 = [
  {name : "john", age: 20}, {name : "sarah", age: 70}
  ];

array1.forEach(element => this.print(element));

print = (data) =>
{
  console.log(data.name);
}
// expected output: "john"
// expected output: "sarah"
```

There is a better way to do this

```js
array.forEach(obj => this.functionName(params));
```

Comment: This answer is not clear to me.